# Installing Ruby with rvm1-capistrano3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano, capistrano3

When I run

```
cap production rvm1:install:ruby
```

I get this error at the end of the console output:

```
Command: cd ~/apps/foo/releases/20140121133714 && ( PATH=/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH /usr/bin/env /tmp/foo/rvm-auto.sh rvm install . )
```

> Could not determine which Ruby to use; . should contain .rvmrc or
>   .versions.conf or .ruby-version or .rbfu-version or .rbenv-version, or an appropriate line in Gemfile.
>   cap aborted!

## EDIT

After adding an `.ruby-version` at the root of my app, with the contents I get

```
DEBUG [af3b80bc] Command: cd ~/apps/foo/releases/20140121160854 && /usr/bin/env /tmp/foo/rvm-auto.sh rvm install .
DEBUG [af3b80bc]    ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not installed.
DEBUG [af3b80bc]    To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247'
DEBUG [af3b80bc]    ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not installed.
DEBUG [af3b80bc]    Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
DEBUG [af3b80bc]    ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not installed.
DEBUG [af3b80bc]    Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
DEBUG [af3b80bc]    No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.10/x86_64/system.
DEBUG [af3b80bc]    Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
DEBUG [af3b80bc]    Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
DEBUG [af3b80bc]    Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
DEBUG [af3b80bc]    RVM does not have prediction for required space for system, assuming 150MB should be enough, let us know if it was not.
DEBUG [af3b80bc]    Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
DEBUG [af3b80bc]    Either the ruby interpreter is unknown or there was an error!.
```

I'm running Capistrano 3.1.1 with `rvm1-capistrano` gem. It's out of the box implementation; nothing special going on.

```
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'rvm1-capistrano3', require: false
# gem 'capistrano-rvm'
end

# capfile
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'rvm1/capistrano3'
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

I'm also getting two other errors in the output:

```
Running /usr/bin/env [ -L ~/apps/foo/releases/20140121135720/public/assets ] on foo.com
Command: [ -L ~/apps/foo/releases/20140121135720/public/assets ]
Finished in 0.291 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/apps/foo/releases/20140121135720/public/assets ] on foo.com
Command: [ -d ~/apps/foo/releases/20140121135720/public/assets ]
Finished in 0.295 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

Comment: your application root does include on of the following files then(?):
`.rvmrc`, `.versions.conf`,`.ruby-version`,`.rbfu-version` or `.rbenv-version`

Comment: @Isotope no. I just added the file though, and now I have a different error message: `ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not installed.` Why would it say that when I'm *trying to install* Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Problem

If you go to the remote server and execute this:

```
cd ~/apps/foo/releases/20140121160854 && /usr/bin/env /tmp/foo/rvm-auto.sh rvm install .
```

you will get the same error but if you execute this instead

```
cd ~/apps/foo/releases/20140121160854 && /usr/bin/env /tmp/foo/rvm-auto.sh rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

success.
The problem appears when rvm-auto.sh execute the `rvm install .` command. Not sure if is a rvm problem but it looks so to my eyes..

### Workaround

If you specify the desired version of ruby to install in `config/deploy.rb`:

```
set :rvm1_ruby_version, "ruby-2.0.0-p247"
```

before executing any rvm1 tasks. Everything should be fine

Answer (score 0):

The application does not know which version of ruby to use.

All you need to do is add a file called `.ruby-version` to the root of your application, and have its contents be

```
1.9.3
```

Or whatever version of ruby you are using.

You may also need a `.ruby-gemset` file. In which case, its contents should be

```
some_gemset_name
```

You can call your gemset whatever you want. It is local to your application.

Comment: Thanks. I added a `.ruby-version` to the root of my add. It's contents are `ruby-2.0.0-p247`. I tried once more `cap production rvm1:install:ruby` and now I get this error:  `ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not installed.` I don't get it. That's the whole point of using the gem, isn't it to install rvm and Ruby automatically? I'm only trying to install Ruby, not deploy.

Comment: That is an old patch level for 2. Just use `2.0.0` in your `.ruby-version` file.

Comment: I tried that. I'm afraid it's not changed the outcome. The documentation makes it sound like it should work out of the box. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. It's been a day already trying to figure this out.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this gem, but does your production environment have rvm installed on it?

Comment: Yes, the gem has three main tasks: `cap production rvm1:install:rvm`, `...:install:ruby`, and `:install:gems`... I already successfully installed rvm using the included task. https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-capistrano3

Comment: Are you at least getting a different error when you don't specify the patch level?

Comment: One thing caught my attention in rvm installation: `To start using RVM you need to run 'source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh'` Maybe capistrano needs to know about this?